# GetLastError() returns 0 to a Failed Window Handle

Tags: c++, windows

I made a program that access a game.
My program is finding the game window with `FindWindow` function, and if the `FindWindow` is failed, the program prints an error message.

My problem is that the `GetLastError` function is always return 0.

("The operation completed successfully.")

- Why does it always return 0 ?

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void GameAccess(LPCSTR winname)
{
    HWND GameWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, winname);
    if (GameWindow == FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to FindWindow & Error Code: " << GetLastError();
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(GameWindow, &procID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

        if (procID == FALSE) {
            std::cout << "procID Failed & Error Code: " << GetLastError();
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    GameAccess("myGame");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running on Windows 95?

Comment: @TanveerBadar No, why ?

Comment: Why are you doing `FindWindowA()` compared to `FindWindowEx()`? Apart from extended functionality, it will also take care of ASCII vs Unicode for you by binding to the correct one depending on the character set you compiled against.

Comment: Don't compare things to `FALSE` that aren't `BOOL`.

Comment: You need to retrieve the last error before you call any other function (and `operator<<` is a function).

Comment: It should be `if (GameWindow == NULL)` instead of `if (GameWindow == FALSE)`. That's not the problem here though because both `NULL` and `FALSE` are actually equivalent to `0`, but still...

Comment: You should also have `if (handle == NULL)` instead of `if (procID == FALSE)`. (I suspect these come from translating the very common `if (!x)` to `if (x == FALSE)`, but they don't really say the same thing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
  HWND GameWindow = FindWindowA(NULL, winname);
    if (GameWindow == NULL) {    // compare to NULL
        auto errorcode = GetLastError();  // 1st thing to do
        std::cout << "Failed to FindWindow & Error Code: " << errorcode;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(GameWindow, &procID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

        if (handle == NULL) {    // compare handle to NULL, not procID to FALSE
            auto errorcode = GetLastError();  // 1st thing to do                 
            std::cout << "procID Failed & Error Code: " << errorcode;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

You also need to close the handle returned by `OpenProcess` if it is no NULL at some point.

`std::cout <<` might do god knows what to the error code.

Comment: @nakE I could reproduce this. It looks like the Microsoft documentation is wrong. Not the first time this happens. There are other unrelated problems in the `else` part BTW.

Comment: Hey! Have you edit your post ? And what do you mean by "unrelated problems", can you explain ?

Comment: @nakE yes, I obviously edited the answer, look at the `else` part and the comments I added and compare it with your original code.

Comment: Have you tried it ? I still getting 0 as error code.

Comment: @nakE read my first comment. I'm also getting 0. I suppose the Microsoft documentation is wrong about `GetLastError()`.